# How to make sure what I commit does not contain whitespace error

Tags: git

Is there a way to tell what I am committing to git does not contain whitespace errors?
I currently is viewing it in my editor line by line. That is very slow and painful.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: What is a "whitespace error" ?

Comment: Is it this ? http://webonrails.com/2008/04/23/git-error-trailing-whitespace-indent-sp-followed-by-a-tab-unresolved-merge-conflict/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
git config —global apply.whitespace nowarn
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know if there is whitespace error, so why I set the above the 'nowarn', isn't that is opposite of what I want?

Comment: like the others, I'm not quite sure what you mean by whitespace <i>errors</i>. I assumed you were trying to ignore whitespace changes.   version control systems usually default to <i>not</i> ignoring whitespace.  You will have to define what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Define 'whitespace error'.  Put that definition in a hook script (.git/hooks/pre-commit) which checks the patch that you are attempting to commit and fails if it contains one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have default `pre-commit` hook turned on?  It includes whitespace check (of a changed part).  You can configure git to tell it what it should consider whitespace error; also if you use color diff then you can tell git to color whitespace errors in diff (including "git show <commit>" output).